# Очередность макетов

Tags: android

При запуске эмулятора, всегда первым прогружается страница main_activity. 
Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы настроить макеты так, чтобы первым прогружалась не main_activity, а допустим, макет регистрации пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым запускается не макет, а объект MainActivity, который по умолчанию использует разметку main_activity.xml. Если вы хотите использовать для этого активити другую разметку - укажите ее в методе onCreate класса MainActivity при вызове функции setContentView.

Если у вас есть другая активити, которая должна стартовать первой всегда вместо MAinActivity, то идем в манифест, ищем описания активити, убираем строки

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

у описания MainActivity и втыкаем их в описание той активити, которая должна стартовать первой.

Если у вас несколько активити, с которых может стартануть приложение(например, у вас есть окно логина и главное активити. Если до этого юзер авторизовался, то сразу грузим главное активити, если нет, то логин), то делают следующее. Создают еще одно активити, условно его зовут SplashActivity. В нем в методе onCreate определяете какое активити надо запустить и запускаете через Intent. Отличная [министатейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/312516/) на тему

Comment: я бы не стал утверждать, что первым запускается именно объект MainActivity, первым запускается именно тот, который отмечен флагом MAIN в манифесте, а его название - дело десятое. Стоит наверное добавить, что то о том, что так происходит в шаблонном проекте. Просто можно подумать, что одного имени достаточно для старта именно с этой активити, когда на самом деле все наоборот. так же не лишним будет добавить, что строки надо "втыкать" не просто в описание активити, а в блок intent-filter

Comment: И еще стоит упомянуть: если пользователь самостоятельно выносил ярлык приложения на рабочий экран, то после таких изменений старая ссылка перестанет открывать приложение.